# Magento2: How to resize image PHP

Tags: magento2

I want resize product image because is too big.  https://prnt.sc/rqfquk

code:

```
                            <?php
                $productImage = $block->getImage($_product, $image);
                if ($pos != null) {
                    $position = ' style="left:' . $productImage->getWidth() . 'px;'
                        . 'top:' . $productImage->getHeight() . 'px;"';
                }
                ?>
```

Can anyone help to slightly reduce the size of the photo?

Comment: take a look at: \Magento\Framework\View\Design\Theme\Image::createPreviewImage
You can also use: \Magento\Framework\Image

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to change the default image sizes, like in the category page, create under your theme `etc/view.xml`

Copy the contents of `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/etc/view.xml` to your custom view.xml, and change the specific values you want, for example:

```
    <image id="category_page_grid" type="small_image">
        <width>240</width>
        <height>300</height>
    </image>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello, is wrong. I want to resize directly in this code from topic

Comment: Hi @Sylvester, sorry. There's a similar answer here which might help: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/187302/resize-and-crop-to-set-width-height-without-stretching  
This would also be useful if you're trying to resize images for a specific template, and not the entire catalog.